fyne.io Extending widgets with custom variables
This may be a Golang question for some. But maybe I'm doing something wrong in terms of how fyne.io is being used. So, here's the problem.
I wanted set percentage width and height for (e.g.) Label widget. So I extended the Label widget as follows.

import "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"

type NewLabel struct {
    widget.Label
    Wpcnt, Hpcnt float32
}

func createNewLabel(text string, w, h float32) *NewLabel {
    lbl := &NewLabel{}
    lbl.Hpcnt = h
    lbl.Wpcnt = w
    lbl.ExtendBaseWidget(lbl)
    lbl.Text = text
    return lbl
}

Then on my custom layout function, when I print the canvasObjects, I see the label with the values I set. But I don't know how to access these values. eg. I cannot use objs[i].Wpct
Here is my custom layout function
func (lo *contentLayout) Layout(objs []fyne.CanvasObject, size fyne.Size) {

    for i := range objs {
        o := objs[i]
        fmt.Printf("cont_layout\n%#v \n\n", o)
    }
    // move and size yet to be done.
}

and here is the output (I formatted it for better readability)
cont_layout
&fyneui.NewLabel{
    Label:widget.Label{
        BaseWidget:widget.BaseWidget{
            size:fyne.Size{Width:0, Height:0}, 
            position:fyne.Position{X:0, Y:0}, 
            Hidden:false, 
            impl:(*fyneui.NewLabel)(0xc000462620), 
            propertyLock:sync.RWMutex{
                w:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, 
                writerSem:0x0, 
                readerSem:0x0, 
                readerCount:atomic.Int32{_:atomic.noCopy{}, v:0}, 
                readerWait:atomic.Int32{_:atomic.noCopy{}, v:0}
            }
        }, 
        Text:"Username", 
        Alignment:0, 
        Wrapping:0, 
        TextStyle:fyne.TextStyle{Bold:false, Italic:false, Monospace:false, Symbol:false, TabWidth:0}, 
        Truncation:0, 
        Importance:0, 
        provider:(*widget.RichText)(nil), 
        binder:widget.basicBinder{
            callback:atomic.Value{v:interface {}(nil)}, 
            dataListenerPairLock:sync.RWMutex{
                w:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, 
                writerSem:0x0, 
                readerSem:0x0, 
                readerCount:atomic.Int32{_:atomic.noCopy{}, v:0}, 
                readerWait:atomic.Int32{_:atomic.noCopy{}, v:0}
            },
            dataListenerPair:widget.annotatedListener{
                data:binding.DataItem(nil), 
                listener:binding.DataListener(nil)
            }
        }
    }, 
    Wpcnt:20, 
    Hpcnt:15
}

See the last two variable (Wpcnt, Hpcnt), which I set in my NewLabel. How can I access these variables within the layout function?
Thank you,
Harshana

You need to cast the type - it's called a type assertion in Go:
o := objs[I].(*NewLabel)

After that you can access the fields like you would expect:
o.Wpcnt


Thank you @andy.xyz for the quick response.
